# Avoid Multiple login with same username and password in rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I don't want to let the user log in into a website more than one time with the same username and password combination at the same instant of time. I am using rvm 1.8.7.

For example, User X logs in with username = sammy and password = sammy123. User Y cannot login with the same username = sammy and password = sammy123 from another machine in the same session before user X logout.

Answer (score 0):

create a table in your database ex: [signin_user] with 3 attributes
1. username
2. login_time
3. logout_time
Whenever user logs in, insert the user's name and the login time into [signin_user].
On all pages which require users to log in, place this condition: check [signin_user] to see if the user's logout_time is blank or not.

Whenever a user presses a logout button, set the logout_time in [signin_user] for that user's name.

If someone tries to log in with an active username and password, check for username and logout_time and display a message stating that the user is already logged in. And, most importantly, set logout_time to MULTIPLELOGIN for that user.

If that user is logged in on any other machine, then if he refreshes or navigates to another page the site will tell him that he has been logged out. Then, the user can be redirected to the homepage of the site.

Answer (score 0):

1.add a column(flag) in table mdl_user store a 'false' value when user create new account .

2.Make a function which accept three value table name,flag field and username(which user enter) .this function return the value of flag field (true or false) .This function call if the user exist in database.

2.1 if 'false' returned then allow to login user and insert value into flag field 'true'. 2.2 if 'true'retuned then do not allow to login and print the message below the username and password field "This user already logged".Do not insert any value in database.

2.3 Now when sign out user then insert into flag field value 'flase'.

3.User allow to login only when flag field value 'false'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using DB table field. Create a field "is_login"(default value is false) in users table(where u are storing username n password). When user logs in to the application turn this is_login field to true and when user logs out turn it to false. Make check while log in. If authentication is successful(username and password) is correct, check for is_login field, if this field is true that means someone is already logged in dont allow the user to login otherwise user can land to their home page.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the session_id in the user-table so you really know who is logged in. If there will be an attempt to log in you first check in the authetication and then check if there is a session in the session_id-column.

If you have an id you can check how long the last action for this session has been. If you decide, there has been no logoff but the session is invalid, you can delete the old session an insert the new one.
If you really want to the are possibilities to set a flag into the "parallel-session" to insert informations to the other session-user.